# Many to Many Relationship in EntityFramework and MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using Code First appraoch in my MVC project. Just for simplicity I have got two `classes Course` and `Modules` where there is a many to many relationship between the entities. Here is the structure of my classes

```
 public class Course
    {
        public int CourseId { get; set; }                  
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Module> Modules { get; set; 
}

public class Module
    {
        public int ModuleId { get; set; }                 
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Credits { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses {get;set;   
 }
```

I created two controllers for each using EntityFramework where each controller creates the table for each class. Now having the many to many relationship the EF is smart enough to create the third junction table for me ie. `CourseModule(FK_Course_ID, FK_ModuleID)`. But the problem is this table is not get populated with the keys from the respective tables. It is blank. Can anyone please help me how can I figure it out??

Thanks.

Comment: Can we see your code where you try to save Course / Module?

Comment: Possibly related, but *all* properties on your POCO classes should be defined as `vitual` in order for entity framework to generate proxy classes for them.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd468057(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I am going out on a limb here but do you have the following in your 
context class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
       base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
                .HasMany(s => s.Modules)
                .WithMany(a => a.Courses)
                .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.MapLeftKey("CourseID");
                    m.MapRightKey("ModuleID");
                    m.ToTable("CourseModules");
                });
}
```

Also, can we see your code where you try to save Course / Module?

Comment: in my context there is nothing other than above along with the Two DbSet. Yes I am using the following:  modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
                .HasMany(c => c.Modules).WithMany(i => i.Courses)
                .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("CourseID")
                    .MapRightKey("ModuleID")
                    .ToTable("CourseModule"));

Comment: I would try to implement to code I have provided above. Obviously, substitute the properties/class names where they do not match your set up. i.e. CourseID, ModuleID etc..

Comment: The CourseModule is being created but not data into it though other tables are populated. Course and Module are separate tables.

Comment: I am not using any my own code to save data. Its the default one created when I add the controller. I haven't touched it.